# connecting postgres database with a C# gRPC Web Application

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, grpc, npgsql

For a school project I am using the ASP.NET Web Application framework with gRPC to make some kind of API. Specifics of this dont matter too much. I am also connecting this API to a Postgres database. I am using the Npgsql library for this.

Perhaps it would have been better to use the Entity Framework Core library during this project, but that's a little late right now, so perhaps for the future. Besides, what I have now works too.

According to the documentation of Npgsql, I need to create a datasource. I can use this instance to open a connection when I need to query something, and at the end I need to close it also. It makes the most sense to do this in the `program.cs` file, since this is the file that contains all configurations of the webserver, as well as the different gRPC services that I am including.

When I made a different program with a RESTfull API, I did it like the piece of code below. In the HTTP Request functions I could just call the database connection directly.

```
\\ configurations
...
\\
var app = builder.Build() // Build the web application

var connectionString = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";
await using var dataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString);

\\ HTTP request pipelines configurations

app.MapGrpcService<Servicer>();
...

app.Run();
```

However, I am using gRPC for this project, and the code where I actually do something with the gRPC request is not in the `program.cs` file. This means that I cannot use the dataSource that I created.

I could create a datasource or connection in each service file, but this does not seem like the way to go because I would have to write some duplicate code each time. It also seems like a really resource heavy operation.

In the end i used a partial class in the `program.cs` file, where I create datasource. Code below. This one I can call in different classes of the project.

```
public partial class Program
{
        public static readonly NpgsqlDataSource dataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(
        "User ID =id;Password=pw;Server=example.com;Port=5432;Database=db;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=true;");    
}
```

Basically, this works, but I was wondering if this is also the "correct" way to do this. Or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a DI container, especially since you have an ASP.NET project.
For npgsql, you can use the provider registration [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.DependencyInjection/#readme-body-tab)(see nuget readme for details).

Once you have registered your provider in DI container, just inject it into the constructor of the gRPC service.